# How to create a function the counts k-tuples of a string?- R

Tags: r

Write a function to create a contingency table of adjacent k-tuples in a string of characters from the set
`A,C,G,T` . For example, with `k=3` and with the string `’CAGACAAAAC’`, you would want to produce the
following table:

```
AAA AAC ACA AGA CAA CAG GAC
2 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

(b) To check your function, run it on a simulated string of 10,000 characters, drawn uniformly and independently
from the set `A,C,G,T` .
I have:

```
x=c("A", "C", "G", "T")
y=paste(x, collapse="")
strsplit(y,split="")
table(y)
```

Not sure what to do from here.

Comment: The second part appears to be homework for which your code is clearly not doing what was requested.

Comment: The data is the set A, C, G, T.  I need to produce a function that will count any k-tuples in a string randomly generated comprised of ACGT.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
x1 <- strsplit(x, '')[[1]]
table(do.call(paste0,as.data.frame(embed(x1,3))))
#    AAA AAC ACA AGA CAA CAG GAC 
#     2   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Or

```
table(apply(embed(x1,3), 1, function(x) paste(rev(x),collapse='')))
```

Or without using `strsplit`

```
table(vapply(1:(nchar(x)-2), function(i) substr(x, i, i+2), character(1L)))
#    AAA AAC ACA AGA CAA CAG GAC 
#      2   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

#### data

```
x <- 'CAGACAAAAC'
```